# Converting a string to a character array

Tags: c++

I'm getting this error

> deprecated conversion from string constant to `char*`

How would I put a string into a char array. Here is what I tried:

```
char result[];
result = "invalid";
```

**EDIT:**

This is what i'm trying to do

```
bool intToRoman (int val, char result[])
{
   MAIN BODY
   result = "MMM";
}
```

in this function i'm trying change an integer into a roman numeral. in my main body I want to store my string (for example "MMM") into my character array result.

Comment: Since this is C++: `std::string result("invalid");`

Comment: Assignment?? Can't use `std::string`?

Comment: `strncpy()` for your case maybe? Again: Use `std::string` to make life easier with [tag:c++]!

Comment: @user3229707 _'i must use char'_ Then use `strncpy()`and all that stuff from the [tag:c] library that's around and don't ask for [tag:c++]! Go check your course text-book ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're planning to change it during runtime, then you can use any of the following options:

```
       char result[] = "invalid"; // 8 bytes in the stack
static char result[] = "invalid"; // 8 bytes in the data-section
```

If you're not planning to change it during runtime, then you can use any of the following options:

```
       const char  result[] = "invalid"; // 8 bytes in the stack
static const char  result[] = "invalid"; // 8 bytes in the data-section
       const char* result   = "invalid"; // 8 bytes in the code-section, and a pointer (4 or 8 bytes) in the stack
static const char* result   = "invalid"; // 8 bytes in the code-section, and a pointer (4 or 8 bytes) in the data-section
```

If you want to initialize it only at a later point during runtime:

```
       char result[] = "invalid"; // 8 bytes in the stack
static char result[] = "invalid"; // 8 bytes in the data-section
...
strcpy(result,"MMM");
// But make sure that the second argument is not larger than the first argument:
// In the case above, the size of "MMM" is 4 bytes and the size of 'result' is 8 bytes
```

Comment: k thanks, might as well ask you another question here too. If i have a     string roman = "MMM". How do I put whatever is in roman into result

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: I've got a feeling that's gotta be something that's gonna make me laugh, though I'm not sure what that problem is...

Comment: @user3229707: `strcpy(result,roman);` (and please accept the answer above if you like it)

Comment: @barakmanos Just a decent advice: Prefer using `strncpy()` over `strcpy()`.

Answer (score 8):

You need to *initialize* the array:

```
char result[] = "invalid";
```

This creates a size 8 array of `char`.

But you may be better off using an `std::string`:

```
std::string result("invalid");
```

Comment: @Borgleader Thanks. I should really learn to type one of these days.

Comment: this is not what i was intended to do. I was trying to declare an array and then later someone in the body of the code put the word invalid in my array.

Comment: @user3229707 **But you may be better off using an std::string!!**

Comment: @user3229707 Then you need to declare an array of the right size, and fill it later. That is quite easy to get wrong, but you don't have to worry because you can just use `std::string`.

Comment: @user3229707 Interesting. Why? It seems like a terrible idea. But anyway, declare a `char` array that is big enough, and then use `strncpy` to copy a string into it.